# Не могу придумать алгоритм для решения задачи на Python

Tags: python, алгоритм, олимпиада

*Условие:*

**Сколько** существует **целых положительных чисел** таких, что их запись в **восьмеричной** системе счисления **оканчивается
на две одинаковые цифры**, запись **не содержит цифр 0**, и сумма цифр в записи равна **8**. В ответе укажите целое число.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Опять при всем уважении к Zhihar...

Но не лучше ли пойти с конца? Рассмотреть возможные варианты окончания — 11, 22, ..., 44 и к ним — количество представлений чисел 6, 4, 2, 0 всякими (ненулевыми :)) цифрами.

```
def cnt(s):
    if s < 0:  return 0
    if s == 0: return 1
    sum = 0
    for i in range(1,7):
        sum = sum + cnt(s-i)
    return sum

sum = 0
for i in range(0, 7, 2):
    sum = sum + cnt(i)

print(sum)
```

Результат верный — те же 43, глубина рекурсии очень небольшая, так что какая-нибудь мемоизация ни к чему.

Сам код — по сути перевод изначально написанного мною на С++, так что если можно написать красивее — перепишите...

Время у Zhihar — [1,06 c](https://ideone.com/nDkqUq), у меня — [0,02 с](https://ideone.com/TJHj8h)...

Answer (score 3):

ну алгоритм то простой:

```
count = 0
for i in range(1, 2396745 + 1):
    # определяем цифры 8ричной записи
    digits = []
    value = i
    while value > 0:
        digits.append(value % 8)
        value = value // 8

    # проверяем условие
    if sum(digits) == 8 and len(digits) > 1 and digits[0] == digits[1] and 0 not in set(digits):
        count += 1

print(count)
```

но вот сколько таких чисел - вопрос, алгоритм пока 43 насчитал, так что тут надо теоретически думать

P.S.

решил, то, что запись не содержит 0, а сумма цифр равна 8 означает, что надо рассмотреть максимум число

```
0o11111111 = 2396745
```

P.P.S.

чуть более быстрый алгоритм - сначала проверяем 2 последние цифры и только после этого разбираем число на цифры:

```
count = 0

for i in range(1, 2396745 + 1):
    digits = []
    value = i

    if value % 8 != (value // 8) % 8:
        continue

    while value > 0:
        digits.append(value % 8)
        value = value // 8

    if sum(digits) == 8 and 0 not in set(digits):
        count += 1
```

Еще чуть более быстрый алгоритм без использования списков и множеств:

```
count = 0

for i in range(1, 2396745 + 1):
    value = i

    if value % 8 != (value // 8) % 8:
        continue

    digits_sum = 0
    digits_prod = 1

    while value > 0:
        digit = value % 8
        digits_sum += digit
        digits_prod *= digit
        value = value // 8

    if digits_sum == 8 and digits_prod != 0:
        count += 1
```

проверку на 2 одинаковые последние цифры можно заменить на более быстрый код:

```
# не анализировать, если последние 2 цифры не равны (в 10 ричной системе это означает кратноть 9)
if (value % 64) % 9 != 0 or (value % 64) == 0:
    continue
```

Comment: `sum(digits) == 8` а это что?

Comment: Действительно, работает! Большое спасибо! А есть ли способ сделать его быстрее?

Comment: а если исходить из того, что 2 последние цифры фиксированы(7 вариантов) и считать нужно только оставшиеся...

Comment: добавил вариант где сначала проверяются 2 последние цифры - алгоритм пошустрее стал работать

Comment: максимальное в восьмиричной будет ... 0o1133... так что варианты с окончанием на 4...7 можно не рассматривать )

Comment: Насколько же умело ты это делаешь! Спасибо! Ты облегчил мне жизнь, я бы, наверное, целый день с этим алгоритмом поролся бы

Comment: A_Vaclav, не понял

Comment: @Zhihar в условии... запись в в восьмеричной системе счисления оканчивается на две одинаковые цифры  И 0 (ноль) не участвует, следовательно максимальное будет  --> 3 + 3 + 1 + 1 Я ОШИБСЯ...

Comment: т.е. вы утверждаете, что 0o3311 (1737) - это максимально число? тогда что по вашему такое 0o11111111 (2396745)? Или вы о другом

Comment: @PaulLocust, добавил еще один чуть более быстрый алгоритм, чем предыдущий

Comment: а ну да... похоже спать нужно идти. Извините

Comment: Тут можно не перебором, слишком большой отсев :) Если перебором - то тогда уж хотя бы перебирать все с суммой 6, все с суммой 4 и все с суммой 2 (+1 для 44 :)) Словом, см. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1349257/195342